# Three.js Custom Stairs Geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to create my own custom three.js geometry for round staircases. But I must have done something wrong with the vertices or indexes of the steps.

Here is a sample staircase that uses my geometry

[image: Sample Image]

Here is my code (The wrong indexes and vertices are at functions generateStepTops Line 177, generateStepFronts Line 259, generateStepSide Line 338

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, controls;

/**
 * 
 * @param {number} radius 
 * @param {number} holeRadius 
 * @param {number} segments 
 * @param {number} angle
 * @param {number} thetaStart 
 * @param {number} thetaLength 
 * @param {number} stepTheta 
 */
function StairsGeometry(radius, holeRadius, segments, angle, thetaStart, thetaLength, stepTheta) {

  if (!(this instanceof StairsGeometry)) {
    throw new TypeError("StairsGeometry needs to be called using new");
  }

  THREE.Geometry.call(this);

  this.type = 'StairsGeometry';

  this.parameters = {
    radius: radius,
    holeRadius: holeRadius,
    segments: segments,
    angle: angle,
    thetaStart: thetaStart,
    thetaLength: thetaLength,
    stepTheta: stepTheta
  };

  this.fromBufferGeometry(new StairsBufferGeometry(radius, holeRadius, segments, angle, thetaStart, thetaLength, stepTheta));
  this.mergeVertices();

}

StairsGeometry.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Geometry.prototype);
StairsGeometry.prototype.constructor = StairsGeometry;

/**
 * 
 * @param {number} radius 
 * @param {number} holeRadius 
 * @param {number} segments 
 * @param {number} angle
 * @param {number} thetaStart 
 * @param {number} thetaLength 
 * @param {number} stepTheta 
 */
function StairsBufferGeometry(radius, holeRadius, segments, angle, thetaStart, thetaLength, stepTheta) {

  if (!(this instanceof StairsBufferGeometry)) {
    throw new TypeError("StairsBufferGeometry needs to be called using new");
  }

  THREE.BufferGeometry.call(this);

  this.type = 'StairsBufferGeometry';

  this.parameters = {
    radius: radius,
    holeRadius: holeRadius,
    segments: segments,
    angle: angle,
    thetaStart: thetaStart,
    thetaLength: thetaLength,
    stepTheta: stepTheta
  };

  var scope = this;

  radius = !isNaN(radius) ? radius : 20;
  holeRadius = !isNaN(holeRadius) ? holeRadius : 20;
  height = !isNaN(height) ? height : 10;
  segments = !isNaN(segments = Math.floor(segments)) ? segments : 8;
  angle = !isNaN(angle) ? angle : Math.PI / 8;
  thetaStart = !isNaN(thetaStart) ? thetaStart : 0;
  thetaLength = !isNaN(thetaLength) ? thetaLength : Math.PI * 2;
  stepTheta = !isNaN(stepTheta) ? stepTheta : Math.PI / 18;


  // buffers

  var indices = [];
  var vertices = [];
  var normals = [];
  var uvs = [];

  // helper variables

  var index = 0;
  var indexArray = [];

  var circumference = thetaLength * radius;
  var height = circumference * Math.tan(angle);

  var stepSegments = Math.ceil(thetaLength / stepTheta);
  var stepThetaSegments = segments / stepSegments;

  var stepHeight = height / stepSegments;
  var halfStepHeight = stepHeight / 2;

  var groupStart = 0;

  generateStepTops();
  generateStepFronts();

  generateStepSide(true);
  generateStepSide(false);

  generateBottom();

  generateSide(true);
  generateSide(false);

  generateEdge(true);
  generateEdge(false);

  this.setIndex(indices);
  this.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
  this.addAttribute('normal', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(normals, 3));
  this.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));


  function generateEdge(isStart) {

    var indexStart = index;
    var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

    var theta = thetaStart;
    if (!isStart) theta += thetaLength;
    var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
    var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
    var startingHeight = halfStepHeight + (isStart ? 0 : height) - stepHeight;
    for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        var activeRadius = x == 0 ? holeRadius : radius;
        vertex.x = activeRadius * sinTheta;
        vertex.y = startingHeight + halfStepHeight * (y == 0 ? -1 : 1);
        vertex.z = activeRadius * cosTheta;

        vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

        normal.set(sinTheta, 0, cosTheta).normalize();
        normals.push(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);

        // uv

        uvs.push(1 - x, 1 - y);
        index++;
      }
    }

    var a = indexStart + 0;
    var b = indexStart + 1;
    var c = indexStart + 3;
    var d = indexStart + 2;

    // faces

    if (isStart) {
      indices.push(a, b, d);
      indices.push(b, c, d);
    } else {
      indices.push(a, d, b);
      indices.push(b, d, c);
    }

    scope.addGroup(groupStart, 6, 0);

    // calculate new start value for groups

    groupStart += 6;
  }


  function generateStepTops() {
    var indexStart = index;

    var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

    var groupCount = 0;


    var activeTheta = thetaStart;

    var activeHeight = stepHeight;

    // Generate Vertices, Normals and UVs

    for (var stepIndex = 0; stepIndex <= stepSegments; stepIndex++) {
      for (var radiusIndex = 0; radiusIndex < 2; radiusIndex++) {
        var activeRadius = radiusIndex == 0 ? holeRadius : radius;
        for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex <= stepThetaSegments; segmentIndex++) {

          var segmentRatio = segmentIndex / stepThetaSegments;

          var theta = segmentRatio * stepTheta + activeTheta;

          var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
          var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

          // vertex

          vertex.x = activeRadius * sinTheta;
          vertex.y = activeHeight;
          vertex.z = activeRadius * cosTheta;
          vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

          // normal

          normal.set(sinTheta, 1, cosTheta).normalize();
          normals.push(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);

          // uv

          uvs.push((vertex.x / radius + 1) / 2, (vertex.z / radius + 1) / 2);

          index++;
        }
      }
      activeHeight += stepHeight;
      activeTheta += stepTheta;
    }

    // Generate Indices
    for (var stepIndex = 0; stepIndex < stepSegments; stepIndex++) {
      for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < stepThetaSegments; segmentIndex++) {

        var segment = (2 * stepThetaSegments * stepIndex) + segmentIndex + indexStart;

        var a = segment + 0;
        var b = segment + stepThetaSegments + 1;
        var c = segment + stepThetaSegments + 2;
        var d = segment + 1;

        // faces

        indices.push(a, b, d);
        indices.push(b, c, d);

        // update group counter

        groupCount += 6;
      }
    }

    // add a group to the geometry. this will ensure multi material support

    scope.addGroup(groupStart, groupCount, 1);

    // calculate new start value for groups

    groupStart += groupCount;

  }

  function generateStepFronts() {
    var indexStart = index;

    var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

    var groupCount = 0;


    var activeTheta = thetaStart;

    var activeHeight = stepHeight / 2;

    // Generate Vertices, Normals and UVs

    for (var stepIndex = 0; stepIndex <= stepSegments; stepIndex++) {
      for (var radiusIndex = 0; radiusIndex < 2; radiusIndex++) {
        var activeRadius = radiusIndex == 0 ? holeRadius : radius;
        for (var heightIndex = 0; heightIndex <= stepThetaSegments; heightIndex++) {
          var heightSign = heightIndex == 0 ? -1 : 1;

          var sinTheta = Math.sin(activeTheta);
          var cosTheta = Math.cos(activeTheta);

          // vertex

          vertex.x = activeRadius * sinTheta;
          vertex.y = activeHeight + heightSign * halfStepHeight;
          vertex.z = activeRadius * cosTheta;
          vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

          // normal

          normal.set(sinTheta, 0, cosTheta).normalize();
          normals.push(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);

          // uv

          uvs.push(1 - radiusIndex, 1 - heightIndex);

          index++;
        }
      }
      activeHeight += stepHeight;
      activeTheta += stepTheta;
    }

    // Generate Indices
    for (var stepIndex = 0; stepIndex < stepSegments; stepIndex++) {
      for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < stepThetaSegments; segmentIndex++) {

        var segment = (2 * stepThetaSegments * stepIndex) + segmentIndex + indexStart;

        var a = segment + 0;
        var b = segment + stepThetaSegments + 1;
        var c = segment + stepThetaSegments + 2;
        var d = segment + 1;

        // faces

        indices.push(a, b, d);
        indices.push(b, c, d);

        // update group counter

        groupCount += 6;
      }
    }

    // add a group to the geometry. this will ensure multi material support

    scope.addGroup(groupStart, groupCount, 0);

    // calculate new start value for groups

    groupStart += groupCount;
  }


  function generateStepSide(isOuter) {

    var indexStart = index;

    var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

    var groupCount = 0;

    var sign = isOuter ? 1 : -1;

    var activeTheta = thetaStart;

    var activeHeight = 0;

    var activeRadius = isOuter ? radius : holeRadius;

    // Generate Vertices, Normals and UVs

    for (var stepIndex = 0; stepIndex <= stepSegments; stepIndex++) {
      for (var heightIndex = 0; heightIndex < 2; heightIndex++) {
        for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex <= stepThetaSegments; segmentIndex++) {

          var segmentRatio = segmentIndex / stepThetaSegments;

          var theta = segmentRatio * stepTheta + activeTheta;

          var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
          var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

          // vertex

          vertex.x = activeRadius * sinTheta;
          vertex.y = heightIndex * stepHeight + activeHeight;
          vertex.z = activeRadius * cosTheta;
          if (heightIndex == 0) vertex.y += stepHeight * segmentRatio;
          vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

          // normal

          normal.set(sinTheta, 0, cosTheta).normalize();
          normals.push(normal.x * sign, normal.y, normal.z * sign);

          // uv

          uvs.push(segmentRatio, 1 - heightIndex);

          // save index of vertex in respective row

          index++;
        }
      }
      activeHeight += stepHeight;
      activeTheta += stepTheta;
    }

    // Generate Indices

    for (var stepIndex = 0; stepIndex < stepSegments; stepIndex++) {
      for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < stepThetaSegments; segmentIndex++) {

        var segment = (2 * stepThetaSegments * stepIndex) + segmentIndex + indexStart;

        var a = segment + 0;
        var b = segment + stepThetaSegments + 1;
        var c = segment + stepThetaSegments + 2;
        var d = segment + 1;

        // faces
        if (isOuter) {
          indices.push(a, b, d);
          indices.push(b, c, d);
        } else {
          indices.push(a, d, b);
          indices.push(b, d, c);
        }

        // update group counter

        groupCount += 6;
      }
    }

    // add a group to the geometry. this will ensure multi material support

    scope.addGroup(groupStart, groupCount, 0);

    // calculate new start value for groups

    groupStart += groupCount;
  }

  function generateSide(isOuter) {

    var indexStart = index;

    var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

    var groupCount = 0;

    var sign = isOuter ? 1 : -1;

    var activeRadius = isOuter ? radius : holeRadius;

    // Generate Vertices, Normals and UVs

    for (var heightIndex = 0; heightIndex < 2; heightIndex++) {
      for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex <= segments; segmentIndex++) {

        var segmentRatio = segmentIndex / segments;

        var theta = segmentRatio * thetaLength + thetaStart;

        var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
        var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

        // vertex

        vertex.x = activeRadius * sinTheta;
        vertex.y = (heightIndex - 1) * stepHeight + (height * segmentRatio);
        vertex.z = activeRadius * cosTheta;
        vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

        // normal

        normal.set(sinTheta, 0, cosTheta).normalize();
        normals.push(normal.x * sign, normal.y, normal.z * sign);

        // uv

        uvs.push(segmentRatio, 1 - heightIndex);

        // save index of vertex in respective row

        index++;
      }
    }

    // Generate Indices

    for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < segments; segmentIndex++) {

      var segment = segmentIndex + indexStart;

      var a = segment + 0;
      var b = segment + segments + 1;
      var c = segment + segments + 2;
      var d = segment + 1;

      // faces
      if (isOuter) {
        indices.push(a, b, d);
        indices.push(b, c, d);
      } else {
        indices.push(a, d, b);
        indices.push(b, d, c);
      }

      // update group counter

      groupCount += 6;
    }

    // add a group to the geometry. this will ensure multi material support

    scope.addGroup(groupStart, groupCount, 0);

    // calculate new start value for groups

    groupStart += groupCount;
  }

  function generateBottom() {

    var indexStart = index;

    var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

    var groupCount = 0;

    var yNormal = Math.cos(angle);

    // Generate Vertices, Normals and UVs

    for (var radiusIndex = 0; radiusIndex < 2; radiusIndex++) {
      var activeRadius = radiusIndex == 0 ? holeRadius : radius;
      for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex <= segments; segmentIndex++) {

        var segmentRatio = segmentIndex / segments;

        var theta = segmentRatio * thetaLength + thetaStart;

        var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
        var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

        // vertex

        vertex.x = activeRadius * sinTheta;
        vertex.y = (height * segmentRatio) - stepHeight;
        vertex.z = activeRadius * cosTheta;
        vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

        // normal

        normal.set(sinTheta, yNormal, cosTheta).normalize();
        normals.push(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);

        // uv

        uvs.push((vertex.x / activeRadius + 1) / 2, (vertex.z / activeRadius + 1) / 2);

        // save index of vertex in respective row

        index++;
      }
    }

    // Generate Indices

    for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < segments; segmentIndex++) {

      var segment = segmentIndex + indexStart;

      var a = segment + 0;
      var b = segment + segments + 1;
      var c = segment + segments + 2;
      var d = segment + 1;

      // faces
      indices.push(a, b, d);
      indices.push(b, c, d);

      // update group counter

      groupCount += 6;
    }

    // add a group to the geometry. this will ensure multi material support

    scope.addGroup(groupStart, groupCount, 0);

    // calculate new start value for groups

    groupStart += groupCount;
  }

}

StairsBufferGeometry.prototype = Object.create(THREE.BufferGeometry.prototype);
StairsBufferGeometry.prototype.constructor = StairsBufferGeometry;

function init() {

  // renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setClearColor(0x404040, 1);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(3, 3, 3);

  // controls
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  var texture1 = loader.load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRSZS.png");
  var texture2 = loader.load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQr6g.png");

  // materials
  material_1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture1
  });
  material_2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture2
  });

  var geometry = new StairsGeometry(2.98, 1.40, 360, Math.PI / 10, 0, Math.PI / 10, Math.PI / 20);
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, [material_1, material_2]);
  mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

  // mesh
  scene.add(mesh);
}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
animate();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

The area that seems to have the problem is

```
for (var stepIndex = 0; stepIndex <= stepSegments; stepIndex++) {
    for (var radiusIndex = 0; radiusIndex < 2; radiusIndex++) {
        var activeRadius = radiusIndex == 0 ? holeRadius : radius;
        for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex <= stepThetaSegments; segmentIndex++) {

            var segmentRatio = segmentIndex / stepThetaSegments;

            var theta = segmentRatio * stepTheta + activeTheta;

            var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
            var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

            // vertex

            vertex.x = activeRadius * sinTheta;
            vertex.y = activeHeight;
            vertex.z = activeRadius * cosTheta;
            vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

            // normal

            normal.set(sinTheta, 1, cosTheta).normalize();
            normals.push(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);

            // uv

            uvs.push((vertex.x / radius + 1) / 2, (vertex.z / radius + 1) / 2);

            index++;
        }
    }
    activeHeight += stepHeight;
    activeTheta += stepTheta;
}
```

Comment: Your code output doesn't seem to match the image you posted. The geometry is even more messed up in the example code. (Your textures are also blocked by CORS.) My advice is to reduce the problem. Make it draw only two steps, so you can look at the vertices and indices without being overwhelmed. I'd start with your vertices, which should be easy to visualize (or plot in a tool like GeoGebra). At a quick glance, your stair tops vertices array only contains two vertices at the same elevation before moving on. You'd need at least 4 at the same elevation to make a plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You calculate the number of steps by dividing the *length* of the stairs (`thetaLength`) by the *length* of one step (`stepTheta`) .

```
var stepSegments = Math.ceil(thetaLength / stepTheta);
```

I suppose that, the input parameter `segments` (which is 3 in your case) is not the total number of segments, but the number of segments for one step of the stairs:

```
var stepThetaSegments = segments;
segments = stepSegments * stepThetaSegments;
```

Further, there are a lot of misalignments in the vertex indices. One big issue is that the tread and the sides of the stairs have to be tiled in segments, but the front of the steps has not to be tiled.
To *see* all the faces, you have to draw all the primitives with the same orientation (counterclockwise). See [Face Culling](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Face_Culling).

See the details of the corrections in the code snippet below.

Preview:

[image]

```js
var renderer, scene, camera, controls;

/**
 * 
 * @param {number} radius 
 * @param {number} holeRadius 
 * @param {number} segments 
 * @param {number} angle
 * @param {number} thetaStart 
 * @param {number} thetaLength 
 * @param {number} stepTheta 
 */
function StairsGeometry(radius, holeRadius, segments, angle, thetaStart, thetaLength, stepTheta) {

  if (!(this instanceof StairsGeometry)) {
    throw new TypeError("StairsGeometry needs to be called using new");
  }

  THREE.Geometry.call(this);

  this.type = 'StairsGeometry';

  this.parameters = {
    radius: radius,
    holeRadius: holeRadius,
    segments: segments,
    angle: angle,
    thetaStart: thetaStart,
    thetaLength: thetaLength,
    stepTheta: stepTheta
  };

  this.fromBufferGeometry(new StairsBufferGeometry(radius, holeRadius, segments, angle, thetaStart, thetaLength, stepTheta));
  this.mergeVertices();

}

StairsGeometry.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Geometry.prototype);
StairsGeometry.prototype.constructor = StairsGeometry;

/**
 * 
 * @param {number} radius 
 * @param {number} holeRadius 
 * @param {number} segments 
 * @param {number} angle
 * @param {number} thetaStart 
 * @param {number} thetaLength 
 * @param {number} stepTheta 
 */
function StairsBufferGeometry(radius, holeRadius, segments, angle, thetaStart, thetaLength, stepTheta) {

  if (!(this instanceof StairsBufferGeometry)) {
    throw new TypeError("StairsBufferGeometry needs to be called using new");
  }

  THREE.BufferGeometry.call(this);

  this.type = 'StairsBufferGeometry';

  this.parameters = {
    radius: radius,
    holeRadius: holeRadius,
    segments: segments,
    angle: angle,
    thetaStart: thetaStart,
    thetaLength: thetaLength,
    stepTheta: stepTheta
  };

  var scope = this;

  radius = !isNaN(radius) ? radius : 20;
  holeRadius = !isNaN(holeRadius) ? holeRadius : 20;
  height = !isNaN(height) ? height : 10;
  segments = !isNaN(segments = Math.floor(segments)) ? segments : 8;
  angle = !isNaN(angle) ? angle : Math.PI / 8;
  thetaStart = !isNaN(thetaStart) ? thetaStart : 0;
  thetaLength = !isNaN(thetaLength) ? thetaLength : Math.PI * 2;
  stepTheta = !isNaN(stepTheta) ? stepTheta : Math.PI / 18;


  // buffers

  var indices = [];
  var vertices = [];
  var normals = [];
  var uvs = [];

  // helper variables

  var index = 0;
  var indexArray = [];

  var circumference = thetaLength * radius;
  var height = circumference * Math.tan(angle);

  var stepSegments = Math.ceil(thetaLength / stepTheta);
  var stepThetaSegments = segments;
  segments = stepSegments * stepThetaSegments;

  var stepHeight = height / stepSegments;
  var halfStepHeight = stepHeight / 2;

  var groupStart = 0;

  generateStepTops();
  generateStepFronts();

  generateStepSide(true);
  generateStepSide(false);

  generateBottom();

  generateSide(true);
  generateSide(false);

  generateEdge(true);
  generateEdge(false);

  this.setIndex(indices);
  this.addAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(vertices, 3));
  this.addAttribute('normal', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(normals, 3));
  this.addAttribute('uv', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(uvs, 2));


  function generateEdge(isStart) {

    var indexStart = index;
    var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

    var theta = thetaStart;
    if (!isStart) theta += thetaLength;
    var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
    var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);
    var startingHeight = halfStepHeight + (isStart ? 0 : height) - stepHeight;
    for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
      for (var x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
        var activeRadius = x == 0 ? holeRadius : radius;
        vertex.x = activeRadius * sinTheta;
        vertex.y = startingHeight + halfStepHeight * (y == 0 ? -1 : 1);
        vertex.z = activeRadius * cosTheta;

        vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

        normal.set(sinTheta, 0, cosTheta).normalize();
        normals.push(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);

        // uv

        uvs.push(1 - x, 1 - y);
        index++;
      }
    }

    var a = indexStart + 0;
    var b = indexStart + 1;
    var c = indexStart + 3;
    var d = indexStart + 2;

    // faces

    if (isStart) {
      indices.push(a, b, d);
      indices.push(b, c, d);
    } else {
      indices.push(a, d, b);
      indices.push(b, d, c);
    }

    scope.addGroup(groupStart, 6, 0);

    // calculate new start value for groups

    groupStart += 6;
  }


  function generateStepTops() {
    var indexStart = index;

    var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

    var groupCount = 0;
  
    // Generate Vertices, Normals and UVs
    var activeTheta = thetaStart;
    var activeHeight = stepHeight;
    for (var stepIndex = 0; stepIndex <= stepSegments; stepIndex++) {
      for (var radiusIndex = 0; radiusIndex < 2; radiusIndex++) {
        var activeRadius = radiusIndex == 0 ? holeRadius : radius;
        for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex <= stepThetaSegments; segmentIndex++) {

          var segmentRatio = segmentIndex / stepThetaSegments;
          var theta = segmentRatio * stepTheta + activeTheta;
          var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
          var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

          // vertex
          vertex.x = activeRadius * sinTheta;
          vertex.y = activeHeight;
          vertex.z = activeRadius * cosTheta;
          // normal
          normal.set(sinTheta, 1, cosTheta).normalize();
          
          vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
          normals.push(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
          uvs.push((vertex.x / radius + 1) / 2, (vertex.z / radius + 1) / 2);
          index++;
        }
      }
      activeHeight += stepHeight;
      activeTheta += stepTheta;
    }

    // Generate Indices
    var v_perSegAndSide = stepThetaSegments+1;
    for (var stepIndex = 0; stepIndex < stepSegments; stepIndex++) {
      for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < stepThetaSegments; segmentIndex++) {

        var segment = indexStart + (2 * v_perSegAndSide * stepIndex)+segmentIndex;

        var a = segment + 0;
        var b = segment + v_perSegAndSide + 0;
        var c = segment + v_perSegAndSide + 1;
        var d = segment + 1;

        // faces

        indices.push(a, b, d);
        indices.push(b, c, d);

        // update group counter

        groupCount += 6;
      }
    }

    // add a group to the geometry. this will ensure multi material support

    scope.addGroup(groupStart, groupCount, 1);

    // calculate new start value for groups

    groupStart += groupCount;

  }

  function generateStepFronts() {
    var indexStart = index;

    var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

    var groupCount = 0;

    // Generate Vertices, Normals and UVs
    var activeTheta = thetaStart;
    var activeHeight = 0;
    for (var stepIndex = 0; stepIndex <= stepSegments; stepIndex++) {
      for (var radiusIndex = 0; radiusIndex < 2; radiusIndex++) {
          var activeRadius = radiusIndex == 0 ? holeRadius : radius;
          var theta = activeTheta;
          var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
          var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

          // vertex
          vertex.x = activeRadius * sinTheta;
          vertex.y = activeHeight;
          vertex.z = activeRadius * cosTheta;
          // normal
          normal.set(sinTheta, 1, cosTheta).normalize();
          
          vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);
          normals.push(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
          uvs.push((vertex.x / radius + 1) / 2, (vertex.z / radius + 1) / 2);
          index++;

          vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y+stepHeight, vertex.z);
          normals.push(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);
          uvs.push((vertex.x / radius + 1) / 2, (vertex.z / radius + 1) / 2);
          index++;
      }
      activeHeight += stepHeight;
      activeTheta += stepTheta;
    }

    // Generate Indices
    var v_perSegAndSide = 2;
    for (var stepIndex = 0; stepIndex < stepSegments; stepIndex++) {
        var segment = indexStart + (2 * v_perSegAndSide * stepIndex);

        var a = segment + 0;
        var b = segment + v_perSegAndSide + 0;
        var c = segment + v_perSegAndSide + 1;
        var d = segment + 1;

        // faces

        indices.push(a, b, d);
        indices.push(b, c, d);

        // update group counter

        groupCount += 6;
    }

    // add a group to the geometry. this will ensure multi material support

    scope.addGroup(groupStart, groupCount, 0);

    // calculate new start value for groups

    groupStart += groupCount;
  }


  function generateStepSide(isOuter) {

    var indexStart = index;

    var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

    var groupCount = 0;

    var sign = isOuter ? 1 : -1;

    var activeTheta = thetaStart;

    var activeHeight = 0;

    var activeRadius = isOuter ? radius : holeRadius;

    // Generate Vertices, Normals and UVs

    for (var stepIndex = 0; stepIndex <= stepSegments; stepIndex++) {
        for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex <= stepThetaSegments; segmentIndex++) {

          var segmentRatio = segmentIndex / stepThetaSegments;
          var theta = segmentRatio * stepTheta + activeTheta;
          var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
          var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

          // vertex
          vertex.x = activeRadius * sinTheta;
          vertex.y = activeHeight;
          vertex.z = activeRadius * cosTheta;
          // normal
          normal.set(sinTheta, 0, cosTheta).normalize();
          
          vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y + stepHeight * segmentRatio, vertex.z);
          normals.push(normal.x * sign, normal.y, normal.z * sign);
          uvs.push(segmentRatio, segmentRatio);
          index++;
        
          vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y + stepHeight, vertex.z);
          normals.push(normal.x * sign, normal.y, normal.z * sign);
          uvs.push(segmentRatio, 1);
          index++;
      }
      activeHeight += stepHeight;
      activeTheta += stepTheta;
    }

    // Generate Indices
    var v_perSegAndSide = stepThetaSegments*2+2;
    for (var stepIndex = 0; stepIndex < stepSegments; stepIndex++) {
      for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < stepThetaSegments; segmentIndex++) {

        var segment = indexStart + v_perSegAndSide * stepIndex + segmentIndex*2;

        var a = segment + 0;
        var b = segment + 1;
        var c = segment + 2;
        var d = segment + 3;

        // faces
        if (isOuter) {
          indices.push(a, d, b);
          indices.push(a, c, d);
        } else {
          indices.push(a, b, d);
          indices.push(a, d, c);
        }

        // update group counter

        groupCount += 6;
      }
    }

    // add a group to the geometry. this will ensure multi material support

    scope.addGroup(groupStart, groupCount, 0);

    // calculate new start value for groups

    groupStart += groupCount;
  }

  function generateSide(isOuter) {

    var indexStart = index;

    var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

    var groupCount = 0;

    // Generate Vertices, Normals and UVs
    var sign = isOuter ? 1 : -1;
    var activeRadius = isOuter ? radius : holeRadius;
    for (var heightIndex = 0; heightIndex < 2; heightIndex++) {
      for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex <= segments; segmentIndex++) {

        var segmentRatio = segmentIndex / segments;

        var theta = segmentRatio * thetaLength + thetaStart;

        var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
        var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

        // vertex
        vertex.x = activeRadius * sinTheta;
        vertex.y = (heightIndex - 1) * stepHeight + (height * segmentRatio);
        vertex.z = activeRadius * cosTheta;
        vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

        // normal
        normal.set(sinTheta, 0, cosTheta).normalize();
        normals.push(normal.x * sign, normal.y, normal.z * sign);

        // uv
        uvs.push(segmentRatio, 1 - heightIndex);

        // save index of vertex in respective row

        index++;
      }
    }

    // Generate Indices

    for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < segments; segmentIndex++) {

      var segment = segmentIndex + indexStart;

      var a = segment + 0;
      var b = segment + segments + 1;
      var c = segment + segments + 2;
      var d = segment + 1;

      // faces
      if (isOuter) {
        indices.push(a, d, b);
        indices.push(b, d, c);
      } else {
        indices.push(a, b, d);
        indices.push(b, c, d);
      }

      // update group counter

      groupCount += 6;
    }

    // add a group to the geometry. this will ensure multi material support

    scope.addGroup(groupStart, groupCount, 0);

    // calculate new start value for groups

    groupStart += groupCount;
  }

  function generateBottom() {

    var indexStart = index;

    var normal = new THREE.Vector3();
    var vertex = new THREE.Vector3();

    var groupCount = 0;

    var yNormal = Math.cos(angle);

    // Generate Vertices, Normals and UVs

    for (var radiusIndex = 0; radiusIndex < 2; radiusIndex++) {
      var activeRadius = radiusIndex == 0 ? holeRadius : radius;
      for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex <= segments; segmentIndex++) {

        var segmentRatio = segmentIndex / segments;

        var theta = segmentRatio * thetaLength + thetaStart;

        var sinTheta = Math.sin(theta);
        var cosTheta = Math.cos(theta);

        // vertex

        vertex.x = activeRadius * sinTheta;
        vertex.y = (height * segmentRatio) - stepHeight;
        vertex.z = activeRadius * cosTheta;
        vertices.push(vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z);

        // normal

        normal.set(sinTheta, yNormal, cosTheta).normalize();
        normals.push(normal.x, normal.y, normal.z);

        // uv

        uvs.push((vertex.x / activeRadius + 1) / 2, (vertex.z / activeRadius + 1) / 2);

        // save index of vertex in respective row

        index++;
      }
    }

    // Generate Indices

    for (var segmentIndex = 0; segmentIndex < segments; segmentIndex++) {

      var segment = segmentIndex + indexStart;

      var a = segment + 0;
      var b = segment + segments + 1;
      var c = segment + segments + 2;
      var d = segment + 1;

      // faces
      indices.push(a, d, b);
      indices.push(b, d, c);

      // update group counter

      groupCount += 6;
    }

    // add a group to the geometry. this will ensure multi material support

    scope.addGroup(groupStart, groupCount, 0);

    // calculate new start value for groups

    groupStart += groupCount;
  }

}

StairsBufferGeometry.prototype = Object.create(THREE.BufferGeometry.prototype);
StairsBufferGeometry.prototype.constructor = StairsBufferGeometry;

function init() {

  // renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  renderer.setClearColor(0x404040, 1);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // camera
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
  camera.position.set(3, 3, 3);

  // controls
  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  loader.setCrossOrigin("");
  var texture1 = loader.load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/hardwood2_diffuse.jpg");
  var texture2 = loader.load("https://threejs.org/examples/textures/crate.gif");
  
  // materials
  material_1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    //color: "red"
    map: texture1,
  });
  material_2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    //color: "blue"
    map: texture2,
  });

  var geometry = new StairsGeometry(2.98, 1.40, 3.60, Math.PI / 10, 0, Math.PI / 2, Math.PI / 10);
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, [material_1, material_2]);
  mesh.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;

  // mesh
  scene.add(mesh);
}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();
animate();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```